# Is there a way to change a text in a Wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I've installed a paid plugin called Zipcode checker. But sadly there is no support with translations. The developer of the plugin is telling me they don't have the functionality for language changing. I tried Loco Translate and it didn't work. WPML did partly the job.

It worked to translate some words in the code of this plugin. There is one more word that I am unable to translate in the code.

When I use the zipcode checker on the site (on the right in the menu) and I use as example 8494 it gives me results. The word YES is what i want to translate to Dutch= JA. I tried but it's not working.

I hope this is the right code:

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "zip_code_checker";
if ( !empty($creds['zip_code']) ) {
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM '.$table_name.' WHERE zip_code = "'. $creds['zip_code'] .'" AND company = "FedEx" AND status IN( "Yes","yes" ) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1', ARRAY_A );
    if(empty($results)) {
        $results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM '.$table_name.' WHERE zip_code = "'. $creds['zip_code'] .'" AND company != "India Post" AND status IN( "Yes","yes" ) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1', ARRAY_A );
    }
    if(empty($results)) { 
        $results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM '.$table_name.' WHERE zip_code = "'. $creds['zip_code'] .'" AND company = "India Post" ORDER BY id LIMIT 1', ARRAY_A );
    }
}
```

The url of the website is : https://graphicfish.nl/kaasboersiebren/

I know that updates of the plugin will erase my changes.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: the page sends an xhr (ajax) request to a file called 'admin-ajax.php', which responds with json `{"id":"7","zip_code":"8494","company":"Kaasboer Siebren","message":"Donderdag 14:10-16:30 uur","status":"Yes","cod":"Yes","success":1}`.

Comment: I think this is not possible.

Comment: Thank you for responses. I found a file called admin-ajax.php but that is placed in the wp-admin folder. I found nothing with Yes to change there.

Comment: @berend 

I have a solution to not display the result YES with CSS. This code worked for the whole zipchecker widget. 

`.sidebar_zip_code_checker_success {
    display: none;}`


Now Levering and YES should not be shown. How do I get this right in the CSS code?

Comment: It worked with CSS code. Thank you for responses.